# Load Testing Composite C1 CMS Console

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter, load-testing, c1-cms

We have a weird request from one of our client to provide them with load test statistics for the Composite C1 Console. I attempted doing this by using JMeter.
**The Problem:** Everything on the C1 UI is dynamic content. How can one write a generic test suite which targets specific fields on the page. I know Composite C1 is pretty new but any rough guide and ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried C1 Log Viewer? You can add primitive "marks" like:

```
Log.LogInformation("my test","test point 1");
```

To check speed of console you can inspect logs with "Verbose" title "ConsoleFacade".. start here:

```
2014 09 01  16:49:37.92 50  342 Verbose ConsoleFacade   Console unregistred by 'admin' id = 'key20218859356246321'
```

finish:

```
2014 09 01  16:49:51.02 50  350 Verbose ConsoleFacade   New console registred by 'admin' id = 'key12416624995518122'
```